# Android Background Location Updates - Different Number of LatLongs in Kitkat And Marshmallow Devices

Tags: android, gps, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-doze

I am developing an app that gets current latlongs of a device and stores them in a file in a new line. I ran my app on kit kat version 4.4.4 and on marshmallow version 6.0.1. I took both device in my car for testing and took a long ride around the city. I noticed a weird output, the file generated from kit kat had 576 lines means that 576 pair of latlongs were recorded. But in the file generated on marshmallow device had only 250 lines of latlongs. As long as I know, according to the definition of Doze mode introduced in marshmallow, the phone only enters doze mode when the device is stationary. But in my case the device was not stationary because it was in a moving car. I am confused. Can anyone help.

Below is my Background Service Class without file saving code.

```
public class GPSTrackerService extends Service {

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
    mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getApplicationContext());
    createLocationCallback();
    createLocationRequest();
    buildLocationSettingsRequest();

    new CountDownTimer(9900000,3000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            Log.d("BOSS_DK","On Tick");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void test(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if (pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
    else {
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
private SettingsClient mSettingsClient;
// Start Fused Location services
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    // create the locatioon request and set parameters
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(2000);  // will return location after every 5 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);  // fastest rate app can handle updates
    //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(5);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

private void buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
    // get current locations settings of user's device
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

    startLocationUpdates();
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    // if settings are satisfied initialize location requests
    mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
            //locUpdates = true;
            // All location settings are satisfied.
            //noinspection MissingPermission - this comment needs to stay here to stop inspection on next line
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
        }
    })
            // if settings need to be changed prompt user
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
}

// stop location updates
private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    //locUpdates = false;
    mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        }
    });
}

private void createLocationCallback() {
    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            List<Location> locations = locationResult.getLocations();
            /*if(locationResult.getLastLocation().hasAccuracy()) {
                setLatLong(locationResult.getLastLocation());
            }*/
            for(Location location : locations){
                setLatLong(location);
            }
        }
    };
}

// Set new latitude and longitude based on location results
public void setLatLong(Location location) {
    Log.d("BOSS_DK",String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("BOSS_DK","service destroyed");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is due to Background Location Limitation. States:

Location retrieval behaviour is particularly important to keep in mind if your app relies on real-time alerts or motion detection while running in the background.

The system distinguishes between foreground and background apps. An app is considered to be in the foreground if any of the following is true:

It has a visible activity, whether the activity is started or paused.
It has a foreground service.
Another foreground app is connected to the app, either by binding to one of its services or by making use of one of its content providers. For example, if a foreground app binds to any of the following components within another app, that other app is considered to be in the foreground:
Input method editor (IME)
Wallpaper service
Notification listener
Voice or text service
If none of those conditions is true, the app is considered to be in the background.

Comment: these limitations were introduced in android oreo. Not in marshmallow.